# Monodevelop AddIn - Custom category node

Tags: monodevelop, add-in

I followed [this](http://www.monodevelop.com/developers/articles/creating-a-simple-add-in/) tutorial but they didn't told me how to create own node.

Their code is creating item **Edit/Insert Date** but I want something like **Edit/Insert/Date**

From that tutorial it looks like I have to add  but I don't know where because I tried to add it everywhere and it told me that I cannot extend that node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your Insert menu inside an ItemSet.

```
<Extension path = "/MonoDevelop/Ide/Commands/Edit">
    <ItemSet id = "Insert" _label = "Insert">
        <Command id = "DateInserter.DateInserterCommands.InsertDate"
                 _label = "Insert Date"
                 _description = "Insert the current date" />
    </ItemSet>
</Extension>
```